# How to change distutils' output directory?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, distutils

When using `python setup.py build` with this code:

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="temp"))
```

the .pyd library is produced in `.\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\module1.pyd`.

**How to make the output .pyd file to the current folder `.` instead?**

Note: the `cythonize` parameter `build_dir="temp"` works: the `module1.c` file produced by cython is in `temp\` indeed. My question is about the output .pyd file.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to

```
python setup.py build --help
```

I found that the solution is to use the parameter `build-lib`:

```
python setup.py build --build-lib=.
```

Then the .pyd files will be created in the same folder as the .pyx Cython files.

---

In the case you don't want to pass it as command-line argument, this is also possible:

```
setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build'], 
                                            options={'build':{'build_lib':'.'}})
```

Another alternative with `inplace` option of `build_ext` (it finally does the same):

```
setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build_ext'], 
                                            options={'build_ext':{'inplace':True}})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the argument `--dist-dir=[default: dist]` option.

> ```
>   --dist-dir (-d)   directory to put the source distribution archive(s) in
>                     [default: dist]
> ```

[Read more about packaging here.](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

You can use the following:
`python3 setup.py sdist --dist-dir=your-dir`

Comment: You cannot use `dist_dir` in `setup()`; did you look into the packaging document I have attached?

Comment: You weren't running the correct command; you need to run: `python setup.py sdist --dist-dir=.`

Comment: I already looked at this packaging documentation @JulianCamilleri, but `dist-dir` doesn't work in the case of Cython libraries with `build`. See my other answer.

Comment: Glad you found your answer! :)

Comment: I found it thanks to you, you pointed me to the right place (command-line arguments) :) +1 for your answer!