# specify *.pyd output path?

Tags: python, compilation, package, cython

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344934/specify-cython-output-file), the answer is for the output path of `.c` files.

I want to know how can I output all the `.pyd` file to a specific directory (by default, it mingles with the source code), for example, the directory `pyd/` in the source code.

[image]

Comment: And adding build_dir=“pyd“ to setup-arguments (not cythonize arguments) doesn’t work? In this case we need to see the setup.py.

Comment: @ead unknown distribution option : 'build_dir', in setup function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the command-line argument `--build-lib your/desired/output/path` to the `python` invocation which executes `setup.py`.

Also, this option is not compatible with `--inplace`. If you're using that, remove it.

Comment: `python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --build-lib pyd/` not working

Comment: @buzhidao What happens if you don't specify `--inplace`?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbeled upon a similar problem and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173314/how-to-change-distutils-output-directory).

When writing your setup.py file you can directly specify the command line arguments, rather than passing them during execution :

```py
from psutil import cpu_count
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

build_directory = "./build"  # Here you will have your C or C files

pyd_directory = "./pyd/"  # The directory for your pyd file
pyx_name = "your_cython_script.pyx"

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        pyx_name,
        annotate=True,  # Generate html
        language_level=3,  # Python 3
        nthreads=cpu_count(logical=True),  # Faster compilation
        build_dir=build_directory,
    ),  # Build directory
    options={
        "build": {  # Here you can specify all the command-line arguments
            "build_lib": pyd_directory
        }
    },
)
```